# Unable to print values of an array in Tabular format in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Trying to print out values of an arrays in tabular format (in the pic) but it doesn't seem to be working. I know it has something to do with the for loop and but I'm not sure how to code it properly so it shows.
The array is user inputed so it could vary on how many "gifts" there are.
If I forgot to include anything, sorry this is my first post

```
public static void printGiftsReport(String[] giftArray, double[] priceArray,
        String[] whomArray, double overUnderAverage)
{
// 
{

    System.out.printf("%-15s%10s%15s%15s%25s" ," #.", "For", "Gift", 
            "Price", "Over/ Under Average\n");
    System.out.printf("%-15s%10s%15s%15s%25s", "---", "---", "----", 
             "-----", "-------------------\n");
    for(int i = 0; i > whomArray.length ; i++) 
    {           
        if (priceArray[i] > overUnderAverage)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10s%25s%10.2f%25s", (i+1), 
                    whomArray[i], giftArray[i], priceArray[i], "over\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.printf("%-10s%10s%25s%10.2f%25s", (i+1), 
                    whomArray[i], giftArray[i], priceArray[i], "under\n");
        }
```

[image: instructions]

Comment: What is the expected vs actual output?

Comment: Actual output will look like the picture

Comment: It's your homework ?

Comment: before you index into an array, especially if as you say the input can vary and especially since you're indexing into 3 different arrays with the same index, you should consider checking that the `i` you're using is actually inbounds for each array.

Comment: What is the output when you run it?

Comment: @Nik *"Actual output will look like the picture"* No. That's the expected output. Actual output is what your program is actually doing, and you don't say in what way it's not the same. Show the actual output.

Answer (score 3):

you're doing `i>whomArray.Length` which will never run since `i` is initialized to `0`. what you want instead is `i<whomArray.Length`.

Comment: that worked, its displaying, i love you